# GCP Datastore Querying on nested entity references (entityB.name)

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, datastore, spring-cloud-gcp

I am having trouble figuring out if GCP Datastore supports querying nested properties of an entity.

My use case right now is like so:

```
Module
  -> Application
```

Module

[image]

Application

[image]

```java
@Entity
class Module {
  Long id;

  @Reference
  Applicaiton application;
}
```

```java
@Entity
class Application {
  Long id;
  String name;
}
```

I want to try query the module based on its nested `Application` name. I have tried providing the filter like so without success:

```java
Query<? extends BaseEntity> query = Query.newEntityQueryBuilder()
    .setKind("module") 
    .setFilter(PropertyFilter.eq("application.name", "UserApp"))
    .build();
```

I'm using Springs GCP datastore abstraction through their DatastoreTemplate, but this doesn't seem related given that when I try run the GQL on the GCP console I get no results back either.

```sql
SELECT * FROM module WHERE application.name = "UserApp"
```

Thanks for taking the time to read through this. Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi @BenDol I would recommend you to check the official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#datastore-datastore-run-query-java) to check the differences between your queries and the official ones. Could you also, please, check and see if individually, you can query their data correctly?

Comment: Hi @gso_gabriel, I have already done both of the things you've suggested before coming to Stackoverflow for help. The answer is yes I have checked for differences, there are none and yes data can be queried individually from each kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using a [Reference](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.RC1/multi/multi__spring_data_cloud_datastore.html#_key_reference_relationships) and not an embedded entity.  The Application in module is really a key reference to an Application entity.  Thus the values of application are not an indexed on the Module entity.

Comment: and what to do in such case?

Comment: Get the key for the UserApp Application entity and query on that.

Comment: This is way... but i'm looking for filtering in the same way as with relational db

Comment: Cloud Datastore is not a relational database.  The queries are limited such that the query times are proportional to the size of the result set instead of the size of the data set which limits query capabilities.